# Renaming foreign key properties in code first EF classes causes an exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have generated several classes using EF6 (code first to an existing SQL Server 2012 database). I'm trying to rename auto-generated properties to adhere to some naming conventions, e.g. from `record_number` to `Number`. A `ColumnAttribute` is then used to provide a mapping.

From my observations, this works as long as I'm not renaming a property that is a **foreign key** in the SQL Server database. For example, in the following case, if I rename either `record_store_id` or `record_pool_id` - both are FK columns - an exception is thrown:

```
[Table("internal_records")]
public partial class Record
{
    [Key]
    [Column("record_number", Order = 0)]
    public long Number { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("collection_id", Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CollectionId { get; set; }

    public short record_store_id { get; set; } // Exception if I rename this to e.g. RecordStoreId and add Column("record_store_id")

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]    
    public byte[] record_pool_id { get; set; } // Exception if I rename this to e.g. RecordStoreId and add Column("record_store_id")

    ... // some other properties (not problematic)

    public virtual Collection InternalCollection { get; set; }
    public virtual Pool InternalPool { get; set; }
}
```

I.e. if I use:

```
[Column("record_store_id")]
public short RecordStoreId { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column("record_pool_id")]
[MaxLength(255)]    
public byte[] RecordPoolId { get; set; }
```

an exception will be thrown when using a Linq query:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The properties expression 'e => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(record_store_id = e.RecordStoreId, record_pool_id = e.RecordPoolId)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.DependentNavigationPropertyConfiguration`1.HasForeignKey[TKey](Expression`1 foreignKeyExpression)
```

I have tried using a `ForeignKeyAttribute`, but I must have done it incorrectly as that didn't solve my problem.

`record_store_id` is a PK in `internal_stores` table (mapped to `Store` class) and `record_pool_id` is a PK in `internal_pools` table (mapped to `Pool` class).

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the way `OnModelCreating()` was being updated when I renamed a property. Originally, the code was:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InternalPool>()
    .HasMany(e => e.internal_records)
    .WithRequired(e => e.InternalPool)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.record_store_id, e.record_pool_id })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Renaming (via VS refactoring) e.g. `record_store_id` to `RecordStoreId` changed the 4th line to something like:

```
.HasForeignKey(e => new { RecordStoreId = e.record_store_id, e.store_pool_id })
```

I had to manually change this to reflect my renamed values, i.e. for `RecordStoreId` and `RecordPoolId`:

```
.HasForeignKey(e => new { e.RecordStoreId, e.RecordPoolId })
```